# Export large area data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, large-datasets

I am trying to average an image collection from 2019-02-01" to "2019-02-28 on Earth Engine platform. My goal is to export the data in Google Drive that I can use it in QGIS for other processing. But several time I got an error message. It says ''Error: Export too large: specified 338272704 pixels (max: 100000000). Specify higher maxPixels value if you intend to export a large area.'

```
var aoi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[85.93714952926396, 27.376833254008353],
          [85.93714952926396, 21.187170010173027],
          [89.90596056442021, 21.187170010173027],
          [89.90596056442021, 27.376833254008353]]], null, false);




// get the data
var y2019 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2")
              .filterDate("2019-02-01","2019-02-28");



// add layers to map
var nox = y2019.median()
               .select("NO2_column_number_density")
               .clip(aoi)
Map.addLayer(nox,{min:0.00002,max:0.0005,palette:"lightblue,orange,yellow,red,purple"},"NO2_19");   
Map.centerObject(aoi, 6)

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: nox,
  description: 'NO2',
  scale: 30,
  region: aoi,
})
```

You can find the link [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ce869f318550051946894f74ee7d445)

Comment: So it gives you an error message and tells you how to fix the error. Have you tried doing what it says? Specifying higher maxPixels?

Comment: Just add `maxPixels` argument and set to some value such as `1e9`. If the GEE capacity exceed then you should try to export smaller region and then stich back together in QGIS

Answer (score 0):

specify the large area pixel in Export.image.toDrive i.e. maxPixels: 338272704 //or higher value